# Setting up IntelliJ in Ubuntu

Tags: java, jdk, intellij

I wasn't sure to post here or in the StackOverflow community but here goes...

I have Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS installed on my laptop. I'm trying to set up IntelliJ at the moment. I installed my jdk by running `apt-get install default-jdk` which installed java in my /usr/bin/java directory. However, when coding, I am unable to see the source library code in IntelliJ. I only see the decompiled .class files, which isn't really easy to read, and doesn't contain any comments.

Basically, my question boils down to: How do I download the openjdk 11.0.3 source code and make intelliJ use that?

Answer (score 0):

First install `openjdk-11-source`. Then in IntelliJ go to *Project Structure -> SDKs*, select your jdk and go to sourcepath tab. There you add the file `/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11/lib/src.zip` as source.

Comment: Hi @noeppi noeppi, I tried what you said and it worked. A few clarifications: I went into _Project Structure -> SDKs_, not JDKs. I also selected the already-installed version of openjdk that I got by running `apt-get install default-jdk`, as this is the package that has the actual binaries/class files. Then I clicked on the sourcepath tab as you said

Comment: @Random_User I fixed my answer